# Dictionary comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Dictionary comprehensions

```
num_dict={1:1,2:4,3:9}
twice_num_dict={key: (value if value*2 >=8 else None)for (key,value) in num_dict.items()}
print(twice_num_dict)
```

Dictionary comprehensionsi wanted to create a new dict where only key:value pairs of the existing dict will be there in the new_dict if the value*2 of the first dict was >=8 i used if and else here but idk what to type in else condition so that the key value pair of 1:1 is not printed at all

Comment: This expression is a bit odd: `if value * 2 >= 8`. Better to go with testing `value >= 4`.

Answer (score 2):

You should place your if clause after your for clause in the comprehension, like so:

```py
{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v * 2 >= 8}
```